# What was the Lubavitcher Rebbe's opinion on Maaneh Chochom?

Tags: chabad, zionism, satmar

[Maaneh Chochom](https://chabadpedia.co.il/images/d/dd/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9D.pdf) is a book written by Chabad mashpia [Reb Yoel Kahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoel_Kahn) addressing the book [Vayoel Moshe](https://www.mysatmar.com/docs/shite_hakdoshe/vayoel_moshe.pdf) by the Satmar Rebbe, [Rabbi Yoel Teitelbaum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Teitelbaum).

I'm not familiar with either texts. I'm just curious to know if the Lubavitcher Rebbe commented on this book by his chossid, if he praised it, etc.

Comment: If the rebbe liked it, there would be a haskama from him in the beginning of the book

Comment: side note: Maaneh Chochom is available [here](https://www.truetorahjews.org/sources-shiur-vayoel-moshe)

Comment: Or here: https://chabadpedia.co.il/images/d/dd/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9D.pdf

Comment: Pretty sure it was published only in the early 2000's. So he never saw it.

Comment: @Shababnik The Rebbe didn't give haskamos. In any case, these were personal letters that were only published recently.

Comment: @mroll First edition was published in 5772.

Comment: @shmosel good to know. Thanks